# Multiple Long Concurrent MySQL Queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL database that has around 600,000 records in the largest table. The other tables are fairly small in comparison. The data is somewhat normalized but there is some duplication because I'm using it for personal use and when I tried fully normalizing it, I found the queries to be unnecessarily complex and slow from all of the joins. I am using PHP to execute the queries.

Now, for example, say that the 600,000 record table contains email addresses. Imagine I have about 10 applications/clients that need to retrieve an email address from this table based on conditions and joins and no two clients should get the same email address. So, I created a query that selects an email address and then another query that uses the selected email address to update a flag field to mark the email address as "in use" and so another client cannot take the same email address. The problem is the query to select the email address takes about 25 seconds to execute and when two clients execute at the same time, they receive the same email address. The speed is not an issue because the clients will only be executing this query once every few hours but I need the clients to get unique email addresses.

I'm kind of new to MySQL so I don't know if selecting the field and then setting a flag is the proper way to go about this. Is there a way to set the flag before I select the field? Also, I don't know much about transactions but could this be solved using them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT email FROM myemails WHERE flag = 0 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE myemails SET flag = 1 WHERE email = '$email';
COMMIT;
```

Another possible approach is to generate a unique flag in php and update first i.e.

```
$flag = uniqid();
UPDATE myemails SET flag = '$flag' WHERE flag IS NULL LIMIT 1;
SELECT email FROM myemails WHERE flag = '$flag';
```

Comment: I've thought about this but haven't tried because won't this run into the same issue? Aren't they separate queries? The first one would still take 25 seconds to execute and the second one has to wait for it to complete?

Comment: @user1203585 when you run the 2nd `... FOR UPDATE` it will wait for the 1st transaction to finish at which point the flag will be set.

Comment: I see you've updated it to use transactions. I think I will try this but if two clients execute these queries (using transactions) at the same time, will one succeed and one will fail and the failed one will have to execute again to get an email address? Or will one transaction wait for the other one to complete? Either way, it might be a problem since the 10 clients will all execute the queries at the same time and if they have to re-execute the query or wait for other ones to complete it could take 25*10 seconds for all clients to get unique email addresses. Thanks.